# jquery .change triggered for radio buttons that have an id containing specific string

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do this

```
$("input[id^='card_sf_guard_user_profile_payment_card_']").change(function(){
    $('#cardForm').hide();
    $('#useNewCard').show();
    return false;
});
```

To trigger the function when any radio buttons with ids starting with  `card_sf_guard_user_profile_payment_card_` are selected.

Doesn't seem to pick up the selection of the radios.

Anyone see why?

Comment: how about listening on the `name` attribute rather than the id ?

Comment: Did you dynamically create your inputs? If you are, use `.on()` method for **event delegation**.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rYcwG/. If it does not work then such elements don't exist at the moment you are trying to bind the event handler. In any case, there is not enough information to help you properly.

Comment: Are you sure, you included jQuery?

Comment: What about DOM ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating elements at runtime..? use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('change','input[id^="card_sf_guard_user_profile_payment_card_"]',function(){
    $('#cardForm').hide();
    $('#useNewCard').show();
    return false;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rYcwG/2/)

Comment: thanks, I tried that prior to my posted attempt but was using click not change. Always so simple!